# FAST Search - A composite-field can contain max 8388608 words per document

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, fastsearch

I'm trying to use Fast Search for SharePoint 2010 to index a document that has over 8388608 words (an excel spreadsheet).

The error message I get in the index_producer_0 log is as follows:
WARNING    index_producer_0 indexer_holder: DocError: Sessino ID 0, operation ID 1259, document ID 7679cba7cc490202a75541721642d8d9_sp: Aborted document during indexing at fixml file line 6 column 55129101. Reason: AddWord(bcatcontent, bconf1, 42050L) failed: A composite-field can contain max 8388608 words per document.

Does anyone know why this limit is in place, and if possible how to expand it? Thanks!